# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/sql/SQLExecutionTag

Tags: sql, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, jstl

I'm getting an error when I'm trying to run a JSP file with some JSTL tags specially SQL in it... in Tomcat server.

I can make out.. it clearly says, some problems with SQL but here what i have in my code.;

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<sql:setDataSource dataSource="EMS_DataSource" />

 <sql:query var="qryGet" >
       SELECT ems_emp_id, ems_emp_fname, ems_emp_lname FROM riz_ems_emp
 </sql:query>

 <c:forEach var="row" items="${qryGet.rows}">
      <tr>
           <td><c:out value="${row.ems_emp_id}" /></td>
           <td><c:out value="${row.ems_emp_fname}" /></td>
           <td><c:out value="${row.ems_emp_lname}" /></td>
     </tr>
 </c:forEach>
```

Apart from this, I have correctly closed all my relevant tags.

Someone Please tell me the reason for this error.

NOW: I changed my jars to jsp-api-2.0.jar and jstl-1.2.jar.

now the error i get is ;

> Unable to compile class for JSP:  The method getELContext() is
>   undefined for the type PageContext

Comment: what is `EMS_DataSource` here? have you prepared data-soruce in advance?

Comment: @user3218114 Yes it's data source; i have created a context.xml file at META-INF to connect to the database

Comment: try `${EMS_DataSource}`

Comment: For the NoClassDefFoundError, try the solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25124896/why-cant-the-runtime-find-class/25125034#25125034 . You should have at least gotten the JSP API when you targeted Tomcat in your web project, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding the values for the default database configuration . You should provide your datasource in the `<sql:query>` tag as,

```
<sql:setDataSource var=dbDetails dataSource="EMS_DataSource" />

 <sql:query dataSource=${dbDetails } var="qryGet" >
       SELECT ems_emp_id, ems_emp_fname, ems_emp_lname FROM riz_ems_emp
 </sql:query>
```

Also make sure you have specified the enough attributes for the [sql:setDataSource](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/sql/setDataSource.html) tag.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: I tried as you suggested. But still the problem remains same.;
this is the error i'm getting : 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/sql/SQLExecutionTag

Comment: Have you specified the values such as  username and password each as an attribute for `setDataSource` tag

Comment: Yes i have set properlly. Now i changed the jars to
1. jsp-api-2.0.jar
2. jstl-1.2.jar

so the previous error gone. 

but now i'm getting another error like this , 

Unable to compile class for JSP: 
The method getELContext() is undefined for the type PageContext


please help.